# why do we need to reset index in column of a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_countries = df_can.loc[['Denmark', 'Norway', 'Sweden'], years].transpose()

df_total = pd.DataFrame(df_countries.sum(axis=1))

df_total.reset_index(inplace=True)

df_total.columns = ['year', 'total']

df_total['year'] = df_total['year'].astype(int)

df_total.head()
```

According to the comments, reset the index to put it back in as a column in the df_tot dataframe. Can someone explain why we need to reset.

Comment: isn't it already in your question: *reset the index to put in back in as a column*. Then why do we want index as a column? Because, as designed, `index` is not a part of your data, e.g., if you do `df.values` you don't get the index information.

Comment: okay, i got it,  thanks, i was just confused about the index being reset into column part